# Receiving error when using Move-ADObject to an organizational unit

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to move a user to a different ou but I'm receiving an error. I tried looking online for solutions but no dice

```
$user1 = Read-Host "Terminated User: "

Move-ADObject -Identity $user1.distinguishedName -TargetPath "OU=DisabledAccounts,DC=meme,DC=com"
```

The Error I am receiving is:

> Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

Comment: `$user1` is a string, not an object with properties. You'll have to first use [Get-ADuser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) with a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lotpings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) explains, you need to first get the user object from AD by means of the (string) value that was entered using the Read-Host cmdlet.

Make sure you ask for the `SamAccountName` of the user, because that is what you will need to find the AD user object.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$accountName = Read-Host "Enter the SamAccountName of the terminated user: "

# find the user object using the SamAccountName entered

# Get-ADUser takes a DistinghuishedName, a GUID, a SID or SamAccountName as Identity parameter
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $accountName
if ($user) {
    # Move-ADObject takes a DistinghuishedName or GUID as Identity parameter
    Move-ADObject -Identity $user.DistinguishedName -TargetPath "OU=DisabledAccounts,DC=nfii,DC=com"

    # you can also pipe the object through:
    # $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=DisabledAccounts,DC=nfii,DC=com"
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User with SamAccountName '$accountName' not found."
}
```